# Excel Copy Paste with DateTime matching

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

VBA Help Request:
I have a report that generates 1 column A of "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm" every few minutes duration.
(This is a variable and is different daily depending on activity start/end date & time)]

I will need to transfer this data from Sheet 1 Column A to sheet 2 column B via copy paste.

When I do this during noon, I will need to do this data transfer again at night too.

The idea is before pasting Sheet 1 Column A, I need to check if the 1st cell in sheet1 column A (dd/mm/yyy hh:mm) already exists in Sheet 2 Column B.

If it already exists, start pasting from that exact cell.

If not, paste from the last filled cell in Sheet 2 Column B

Any Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(2)
' So after the headers Sheet 1 Col A Row 16 will be the 1st variable date & time 
k = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(16, 1)
' Find k in Sheet 2
Set rng1 = rng2.Find(What:=k, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

' If not found then paste after last filled cell in sheet 2 col B
If rng1 Is Nothing Then
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' If found start pasting from that same cell in Sheet 2 COl B
Else
rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

My code above dosent work, it instead always paste from below the last filled cell in sheet 2 col B.

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zFoO.png)
Take Sheet 1 as Col A, Sheet 2 as Col C
When I paste my data from Col A to Col C, if the 1st date of Col A already exists in Col C, the data should start pasting form the same cell in Col C.

What I currently have is an example is Col E where the data fails to check if the first date already exists before pasting and always will repeat the same data when pasting.

Comment: Can you show us sample data and expected output for those two cases you describe in your question.

Comment: Hi, I had added an image "Data Example" for your reference. Thank you